# Отдать файл на скачивание по ссылке на другой ресурс

Tags: php, yii2

имеется ссылка на видео на другом сайте. Необходимо отдать на скачивание видео, не скачивая его к себе на сервер.
Так возможно?

Comment: вставить ссылку на видео не?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я может что то не понимаю. Но там ссылка не на скачивание, а просто на ресурс т.е. если по ней перейти откроется видео в окне браузера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно помещать контент файла стороннего ресурса во временный файл который по окончанию скрипта умрет, или после закрытия к примеру:

```
// Link на файл на стороннем ресурсе который нужно скачать
$link = 'https://website.com/folder/file.png|mp4|...';

// Достаем с него расширение и названия
['basename' => $basename, 'extension' => $extension] = pathinfo($link);

// Достаем сам контент по силке
$content = file_get_contents($link);
// Получаем путь ко временному файлу который умрет по окончанию выполнения скрипта
['uri' => $filepath] = stream_get_meta_data(tmpfile());

// Сохраняем контент с ресурса во временный файл
file_put_contents($filepath, $content);

// сбрасываем буфер вывода PHP, чтобы избежать переполнения памяти выделенной под скрипт
// если этого не сделать файл будет читаться в память полностью!
if (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_end_clean();
}

// заставляем браузер показать окно сохранения файла
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $basename);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
// читаем файл и отправляем его пользователю
readfile($filepath);
exit;
```

Comment: Позволю себе `ложку дегтя` в Ваше решение :) Во-первых при БОЛЬШОМ размере файла на стороннем ресурсе или же при медленном Интернете от Вашего сайта до стороннего ресурса (при этом от клиента до стороннего сайта Инет может быть намного лучше) - клиент будет ооочень долго ждать пока же Ваш сайт выкачает файл, а потом уже отдаст ему. Во-вторых, речь идет о видео и не факт что оно лежит одним файлов - скорее всего там поток `rtsp v4` (по сути куча маленьких файлов, скажем по 30 сек, для каждого качества которые подгружаются друг за другом) - такое выкачивается совсем по-другому.

Comment: Спасибо за критику, не могли б вы продемонстрировать верное решения для данной задачи, я был бы очень рад))

Comment: для этого нужны полные условия задачи. Что за тип файла (файл, потоковое видео и тд), какие могут быть размеры, скорость до сайта и тп и тд

Comment: Ну а если полноє рассмотрения темы, со всеми вытекающими, возможно статья какие-нибудь есть, или прохожие ответы? Условия задачи - передача через свой ресурс больших файлов/потоковых видео со сторонних ресурсов. Ну естественно если это не накладно)